# creating health check API

Tags: spring-mvc, google-cloud-platform, health-check

I am trying to create a healthCheck APi for our spring mvc (5.2.1)application in traditional XML config.
I want to capture details like

1. cpu utilization
2. memory consumption details
3. threads in use
4. database in check
5. checking for some 3rd party services like smtp,sms service etc

Is there any library that is readily available which provides all these details or I need to implement it in the application.
Thought to use dropwizard metrics but it doesn't give any details except status for built in healthcheck.So is the indigenous way to build this health check API right way?I just want to be sure that I am going on the right path?
PS:we are going to migrate the application to google cloud.Can we use some google analytics ?

Comment: I think you are confusing `health checks` with `monitoring and metrics`. Health checks are a go/no-go status check. Google has a good product for logging, metrics and monitoring: Stackdriver (Operations Suite). https://cloud.google.com/products/operations There are numerous vendors with software tools also.

Comment: Did you have a try to Spring Boot Actuator? It offers you a endpoint to test with your health check (and you can extend it if you have special needs).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere fiddled with spring boot actuator..but it doesnt seem to be working smoothly with non boot traiditional spring xml

Comment: Hmm maybe, I read somewhere that spring.xml was no longer the recommended was. And so, you should have a lot of documentation. Can you share a minimal piece of code to let me reproduce your use case?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Have posted it here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66074277/spring-actuator-with-non-boot-spring-mvc-not-working](So Link)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66074277/spring-actuator-with-non-boot-spring-mvc-not-working)

Comment: Your main goal is to generate metrics or healthchecks from your application? or want to collect your existing metrics and healthchecks?

Comment: @DavidC both metrics and healthcheck

Comment: I'm trying to understand, you can generate information from your app and route this information to a solution like Google Monitoring  to generate metrics, alerting and health checks. In which step are you? how to generate information from your app? or route the information you already generate into a solution like Google Cloud Monitoring?